# How to check whether s3 access key has access to a specific bucket or not in aws using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to copy files from 2 different bucket which are in two different aws account using same access key.
So it provide an error saying 403 forbidden.So what i want to do is, I want to check whether the access key that i am using to copy the file has permission to those bucket before i copy the file using boto3. Is there are anyway to do this?

Comment: The easiest way to test for permissions is, quite frankly, to try the command. If you still have problems after using the tips below, please show us the permissions associated with the IAM User you are using and the bucket policy on the buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying objects between Amazon S3 buckets that belong to different AWS accounts, then you will need to use a **single set of credentials** that have:

- `GetObject` permission on the source bucket
- `PutObject` permission on the destination bucket

Also, the `CopyObject` command should be sent to the `destination bucket` to avoid problems with object ownership.

Therefore, I would recommend:

- Use **credentials** from the **destination** account (`dest-IAM-user`)
- Add a **bucket policy** to the **source bucket** that permits `GetObject` access by `dest-IAM-user`